# Как подготовить текст с HTML тегами для публикации на стене VK

Tags: php, laravel, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Использую php библиотеку для работы c api vk. Хочу сделать автоматическое дублирование сообщения с моего сайта на стену группы вк. На сайте использую WYSIWYG редактор. В БД текст сообщения заносится с абзацами, отступами и т.п. (`<p></p>, <br> <span style=""></span>`) Но как мне такой текст подготовить для публикации на стене ВК? Если просто отправить, то html теги отображаются там как есть. Их как-то можно убрать и на что заменить? Как тут быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего преобразовать такой текст в markdown. А после убрать оставшийся html код. Для преобразования можно воспользоваться, например `league/html-to-markdown` библиотекой. Для удаления остатков html встроенной в php функцией `strip_tags()`

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags - Удаляет HTML и PHP-теги из строки
https://php.ru/manual/function.strip-tags.html

А для удаления лишних пробелов и переносов используй регулярки или str_replace()